# How do I stop ServiceStack 3.9.71 NuGet package installing ServiceStack.Text 4.0.24?

Tags: licensing, servicestack, nuget, servicestack-text, nuget-package-restore

I have a project that uses ServiceStack; we're running the old 3.9.x codebase rather than upgrading to 4.x, since ServiceStack 4 requires a commercial license.

My own API client has a dependency defined in the `.nuspec` file as follows:

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency id="DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2.Client" version="[4.3,5)" />
  <dependency id="log4net" version="[2.0,2.1)" />
  <dependency id="ServiceStack" version="[3.9.71,4)" />
</dependencies>
```

Problem is - the **ServiceStack** package depends on various other bits of the ServiceStack framework, and installing ServiceStack 3.9.71 is installing **ServiceStack.Text** v4.0.24 into my project. It *does* pop up the dialog requiring license acceptance, which is what alerted me that something weird was going on - but short of manually defining my own dependencies for the other required ServiceStack components, how can I make sure I'm not going to end up with unlicensed bits of ServiceStack 4.x in my project?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make the ServiceStack.Text dependency explicit in your .nuspec and put it before the ServiceStack dependency.

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency id="DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2.Client" version="[4.3,5)" />
  <dependency id="log4net" version="[2.0,2.1)" />
  <dependency id="ServiceStack.Text" version="[3.9.71,4)" />
  <dependency id="ServiceStack" version="[3.9.71,4)" />
</dependencies>
```

This will force NuGet to resolve ServiceStack.Text using the constraint.

The problem with just installing ServiceStack using the version range **[3.9.71,4)** is that NuGet resolves the ServiceStack.Common dependency to the lowest compatible version of ServiceStack.Common which it determines is version 3.9.11. ServiceStack.Common 3.9.11 does not specify a dependency range for ServiceStack.Text so NuGet installs a 4.0 version. Later versions of ServiceStack.Common do have a range for the ServiceStack.Text package but the older versions do not. So without making the dependency explicit or having the ServiceStack.Text NuGet package changed so it puts in a range, there is not much you can do when installing your NuGet package.

The only other thing you can do is put a constraint in your packages.config file to prevent the newer version of ServiceStack being installed.

```
<packages>
    <package id="ServiceStack.Text" version="3.9.71" allowedVersions="[3.9.71,4)" />
</packages>
```

Answer (score 0):

I made my own "wrapper" package for this containing no extra files but only dependencies - like this:

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency id="ServiceStack.Text" version="[3.9.71]" />
  <dependency id="ServiceStack.Common" version="[3.9.71]" />
  <dependency id="ServiceStack.Redis" version="[3.9.71]" />
  <dependency id="ServiceStack.OrmLite.SqlServer" version="[3.9.71]" />
  <dependency id="ServiceStack" version="[3.9.71]" />
</dependencies>
```